# onClick and setOnClickListener() cause my app to unfortunately stop

Tags: java, android

Here's the Java code

```
package com.example.getyourhandsoffmy;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bells);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    public void bells(View view) {
         mediaPlayer.start();
     }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And Here's button XML

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:onClick="bells"/>
```

So the problem is that as soon as I add onClick function to my code or setOnClickListener and try to compile and run the code it tells me that Unfortunately my app has stopped

Comment: When faced with "unfortunately app has closed" errors, always post the  error logcat. (My guess here: NPE involving `getBaseContext()`.)

Answer (score 4):

You're doing things too early here:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bells);
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

When member variables are initialized, you cannot use your activity `this` as a `Context`. This will cause a crash with `MediaPlayer.create()`.

`findViewById()` here will return `null` as it is executed before `setContentView()`. However, it doesn't really matter here since you're not using `button` variable anywhere in the code you posted.

Solution: Move both initializations to `onCreate()`.

Comment: Where do I put bells()? because if I put it outside onCreate it tells me mediaPlayer Cannot be resolved, if I put it inside onCreate it tells me void is an invalid type for variable bells.

Comment: The `bells()` method is just fine the way it is: in the activity class.

Answer (score 1):

You need the below inside onCreate after setContentView

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bells);
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

`findViewById` looks for a view in the current inflated layout.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the Android oficial documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

> The method you declare in the android:onClick attribute must have a
>   signature exactly as shown above. Specifically, the method must:
>
> Be public
>
> Return void
>
> Define a View as its only parameter (this will
>   be the View that was clicked)

1) Initialize both your button and MediaPlayer after your setContentView in onCreate();

2) Add this method:

```
public void bells(View view) {}
```

Comment: I made the same mistake but it is there.